# purrr:modify2 and modify_at

Tags: r, list, purrr

considering following list

```
df <- list(list(a = 1, b = NA_real_, c = NA_real_, d = NA_real_, e = NA_real_), 
    list(a = 1, b = NA_real_, c = NA_real_, d = NA_real_, e = NA_real_), 
    list(a = 1, b = NA_real_, c = NA_real_, d = NA_real_, e = NA_real_), 
    list(a = 1, b = NA_real_, c = NA_real_, d = NA_real_, e = NA_real_), 
    list(a = 1, b = NA_real_, c = NA_real_, d = NA_real_, e = NA_real_))
```

I want to change the value in position "a" according the outer list index like this:

```
df[[1]]$a <- 1
df[[2]]$a <- 2
df[[3]]$a <- 3
```

But I want to use `purrr` functions like

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  modify_depth(1, ~modify_at(., "a", ~. + 1))
```

I'm pretty sure that we can use `modify2` for such thing. But don't get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically the same thing as @tmfmnk but using `modify2()`.

```r
library(purrr)

modify2(df, seq_along(df), ~ list_modify(.x, .y))
```

Note that changes `a` by position. Probably want to do `a = .y` and be more explicit.

I guess piped that would be:

```r
df2 <- df %>% 
  modify2(., seq_along(.), ~ list_modify(.x, a = .y))

df2[3]

# [[1]]
# [[1]]$a
# [1] 3
# 
# [[1]]$b
# [1] NA
# 
# [[1]]$c
# [1] NA
# 
# [[1]]$d
# [1] NA
# 
# [[1]]$e
# [1] NA
```

**Edit:**

Looking at the comment on another answer from @camille, this may be the cleanest.

```r
df %>% 
  imap(~ list_modify(.x, a = .y))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option could be:

```
map2(.x = df,
     .y = 1:length(df),
     ~ update_list(.x, a = ~ .y))

[[1]]
[[1]]$a
[1] 1

[[1]]$b
[1] NA

[[1]]$c
[1] NA

[[1]]$d
[1] NA

[[1]]$e
[1] NA


[[2]]
[[2]]$a
[1] 2

[[2]]$b
[1] NA

[[2]]$c
[1] NA

[[2]]$d
[1] NA

[[2]]$e
[1] NA
```

Comment: `update_list` is a good call. FYI `imap(df)` is a shorter & easier version of `map2(.x = df, .y = 1:length(df)`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not as neat as you'd like, but using `purrr::imap` gives you access to the items' indexes, which you can then assign to each `"a"` element. Just make sure you return the list. AFAIK you'll get the same result with `imodify`.

```r
library(purrr)

df2 <- df %>%
  imap(function(l, i) {
    l[["a"]] <- i
    l
  })
df2[4]
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]]$a
#> [1] 4
#> 
#> [[1]]$b
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> [[1]]$c
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> [[1]]$d
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> [[1]]$e
#> [1] NA
```

Comment: ok. pretty straight forward. I will accept since I can use it that way in my real life setting.

Comment: No need to rush to accept it—someone might come along with an idea about `modify`