# Change values in nested list

Tags: r, list, tidyverse, purrr

Assuming this nested list

```
df <- list(list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4, e = 5), 
           list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4, e = 5), 
           list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4, e = 5), 
           list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4, e = 5), 
           list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4, e = 5))
```

Now, I want to change some values for variable `d` in list indeces `c(2, 5)`.
One expected output is:

```
list(list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4, e = 5), 
     list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 50, e = 5), 
     list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4, e = 5), 
     list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4, e = 5), 
     list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 50, e = 5))
```

Another output contains different values for d such as `c(50, 100)`

I already asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60417444/purrrmodify2-and-modify-at), but I have no idea how to transform the suggested functions to get results per indeces without using `for` loops. Approaches using pipes are prefereed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `purrr`:

**Assign by name**

```
library(purrr)

df[c(2, 5)] <- map2(df[c(2, 5)], c(50, 100), ~ list_modify(.x, d = .y))
```

If you load the library `magrittr` you can simplify to:

```
library(purrr)
library(magrittr)

df[c(2, 5)] %<>% map2(c(50, 100), ~ list_modify(.x, d = .y))
```

**Assign by element position**

Use `assign_in`:

```
df[c(2, 5)] %<>% map2(c(50, 100), ~ assign_in(.x, 4, .y))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Map`

```
df[c(2, 5)] <- Map(function(x, y) {x$d <- y; x}, df[c(2, 5)], c(50, 100))
```

Answer (score 1):

Not as elegant of a solution as Akrun's, but perhaps you can write a function to select an element value in the nested list and rewrite to a new value, and then use `lapply()` to have it work on the "meta-list," and overwrite the changed nested lists.  Here's an example

```
##Example Data##
df <- list(list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4, e = 5), 
           list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4, e = 5), 
           list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4, e = 5), 
           list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4, e = 5), 
           list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4, e = 5))

##Function to extract an element from nested list and rewrite to a new value##
List_fxn<-function(LIST, ELEMENT, NEW_VALUE){
  LIST[names(LIST)==ELEMENT]<-NEW_VALUE
  return(LIST)
}

##Run the function on nested lists 2 and 5, then overwrite nested lists 2 and 5 in df##
df[c(2,5)]<-lapply(df[c(2,5)], List_fxn, ELEMENT = "d", NEW_VALUE = 100)

##View the results##
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `[<-` like below

```
df[c(2,5)] <- Map(`[<-`,df[c(2,5)],"d",c(50,100))
```

which gives

```
> df
[[1]]
[[1]]$a
[1] 1

[[1]]$b
[1] 2

[[1]]$c
[1] 3

[[1]]$d
[1] 4

[[1]]$e
[1] 5


[[2]]
[[2]]$a
[1] 1

[[2]]$b
[1] 2

[[2]]$c
[1] 3

[[2]]$d
[1] 50

[[2]]$e
[1] 5


[[3]]
[[3]]$a
[1] 1

[[3]]$b
[1] 2

[[3]]$c
[1] 3

[[3]]$d
[1] 4

[[3]]$e
[1] 5


[[4]]
[[4]]$a
[1] 1

[[4]]$b
[1] 2

[[4]]$c
[1] 3

[[4]]$d
[1] 4

[[4]]$e
[1] 5


[[5]]
[[5]]$a
[1] 1

[[5]]$b
[1] 2

[[5]]$c
[1] 3

[[5]]$d
[1] 100

[[5]]$e
[1] 5
```